# Idiom Where You Have Connections in the Government

Tags: idioms

I live in a corrupt country. There are some people who own establishments beside the road. They closed the whole public road so they can use it for their customers' parking.

I'm finding an idiom on this. Like when you can easily ask for favor from the people in government if you know them personally or you give them money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We refer to *having friends in high places*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-friends-in-high-places)
>
> *have friends in high places*:
>
> to know important people who can help you get what you want

Here are two examples of this usage:

> [RadioFreeEurope](https://www.rferl.org/a/kyrgyzstan-election-commission-/31548082.html)
>
> Mamytov will almost surely be a candidate when election day arrives. He has friends in high places.
>
> In 2013, Mamytov was on trial with current President Sadyr Japarov and the current head of the State Committee for National Security, Kamchybek Tashiev, for creating public unrest and trying to overthrow the government in October 2012.

> [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2002/feb/06/worldcupfootball2002.sport)
>
> While the rest of the country may have questioned Emile Heskey's seemingly divine right to an England shirt, the faith of two men has never wavered. Fortunately for Emile, he has friends in high places. Gerard Houllier and Sven-Goran Eriksson have consistently ignored the claims of more naturally gifted strikers, and a goal-scoring record that compares unfavourably with Ade Akinbiyi's, and made Heskey their first choice for club and country.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for two different idioms.  I don't know one idiom that covers both situations in English.

1. Using the personal connection:

**Know the right person** -- note, this might not be someone high up.

Example: *He can get that ticket fixed for you.  He knows the right person/people.*

2. Paying someone off with a bribe:

(a) **Grease someone's palm** -- Give someone money in exchange for a favor; also, bribe someone. American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms, published at the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grease+someone%27s+palm).

(b) **Pay someone under the table** -- this is an alternative but it needs some context for it to be clear that there is a bribe.  You could use this one occasionally for variety.

Comment: Where You Have Connections [to a corrupt] Government : *one hand washes the other*